# How to Share Backend in AWS Amplify Applications

Tags: aws-amplify

I'm totally new to Amplify (and FE in general). My objective is to have an Amplify application which has the auth backend and another Amplify application that uses this backend. (Something like a webapp + a mobile app). I know there's this thing called multi-frontend (or shared-backend) described [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/teams/multi-frontend) and am trying to do what the guide says, but when I do `amplify pull` nothing happens on the second app (in the guide it shows the list of app to select and continue with pulling). Not sure what I'm missing there.

Generally my question is how to pull backend stuff from an Amplify application (which is in a different repository) into another Amplify application.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, have the same question. Following the Amplify Docu doing an `amplify pull` still leaves you with just **one** Amplify App.
How to make it **two** Amplify Apps, having the second one using the backend ressources of the first?

Comment: Did you push it at the end? So basically amplify pull, just pull the backend (resource information) into the current repository (essentially add `aws-exports.js`). Let me know if you need help with this.